# With the Arcgis SDK, Is it possible to store a tile package (.tpk) or a compact cache on the sdcard in a Windows Store App ?

Tags: sd-card, arcgis, windows-store

I can successfully load a .tkp package in a Windows Store App using the Arcgis SDK when the file is stored in the AppData Folder or the Instal Folder off the App.

Like this :

```
        StorageFile sf = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Test.tpk");

        Layer bkgLayer = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer(sf);

        Map.Layers.Add(bkgLayer);
```

note : ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder is the standard local folder :
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\app_guid\LocalState

**=> The base map is successfully displayed.**

But, I have to store the data to the sd card or another folder like My document

So I use :

```
       StorageFile sf= await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Test.tpk");

        Layer bkgLayer = new ArcGISLocalTiledLayer(sf);

        Map.Layers.Add(bkgLayer);
```

**=> The base map is not displayed**

In the application manifest, I have access to the documents folder and to .tpk files.  I can successfully read and write in this folder using a Stream.

I notice that in the SDK documentation we can read :

> *ArcGISLocalTiledLayer(StorageItem) : The storage file must be located in a location accessible by the app, ie only local data and app
>   storage. If the file resides outside these folders, it must be copied
>   to the local data store first.*

So, is it a limitation of the Argis SDK or I made something wrong ?

Is there another way to store a base map outside the AppData folder ?

(The size of the base map is 40Go, and I have to share it between multiple user account)

Thanks a lot for any help :)